# how to group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

[image: Table]

I want to get the `sum` of the ages of the three groups (**A** and **B** | **C** and **D** | **E** and **F**)

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your question breh?

Comment: Where are the groups?

Comment: @Eugene A and B | C and D | E and F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH sample_data AS
  (SELECT 1 AS id, 10 AS age, 11 AS name, 'A' AS type FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 0, 1, 'B' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 9, 11, 'C' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 10, 11, 'D' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 10, 11, 'E' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 10, 11, 'F' FROM dual
  )
SELECT listagg(type,',') within GROUP (
ORDER BY type) types,
  SUM(age)
FROM sample_data
GROUP BY DECODE(type,'A',1,'B',1,'C',2,'D',2,3)
```

result

```
types    sum(age)
A,B        10
C,D        19
E,F        20
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN TYPE IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'AB'
         WHEN TYPE IN ('C', 'D') THEN 'CD'
         WHEN TYPE IN ('E', 'f') THEN 'Ef'
       END AS KIND,
       SUM(AGE) AS TOTAL_AGES
  FROM WHATEVER_TABLE
  GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN TYPE IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'AB'
             WHEN TYPE IN ('C', 'D') THEN 'CD'
             WHEN TYPE IN ('E', 'f') THEN 'Ef'
           END;
```